# Rescalling a range of numbers depending on the interval they belong to

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following conversion table:

[image]

and I need to convert the values of the second column to the values in the first column, as continuous variables.

Currently, I am trying to write a function that accepts a value from the second column, check its validity and then uses the following conversion formula for the data transformation:

[image]

The code currently looks like this:

```
Public Function ReScale (input As Double)

  'Max and Min values of the old scale.
   Dim MinOld As Double: MinOld = 2
   Dim MaxOld As Double: MaxOld = 6

  'Test input value validity.
   If input > MaxOld Or input < MinOld Then
     ReScale = CVErr(xlErrNA)
   End

   Dim MinNew As Double
   Dim MaxNew As Double

   'Find in which interval the input value belongs.
   If input >= 5.5 Then
     MinOld = 5.5
     MaxOld = 6.0
     MinNew = 85
     MaxNew = 100
   ElseIf input >= 4.50 And input <= 5.49 Then
     MinOld = 4.50
     MaxOld = 5.49
     MinNew = 65
     MaxNew = 84
   ...` <--------------------- Question?

  'Transform the old data to the new scale.
   ReScale = ( (MaxNew - MinNew) / (MaxOld - MinOld) ) * (input - MaxOld) + MaxNew

End Function
```

My question is:

Should I search for `MaxNew`, `MinNew`, `MaxOld` and `MinOld` depending on the variable value or should I use the absolute minimum and maximum?

Is there an easier way of doing this?

---

Comment: Why do you need the `<=` check in those `ElseIf` statement?  (Unless you want to handle 5.495 as a special case?)

Comment: since the conversion table  shows there is no liner relation, my opinion is to proceed with current approach only for accurate conversion.

Comment: @Chronocidal oh, yes! You are right, it should just be `< 5.50`, instead of `<=5.49`, right?

Comment: @AhmedAU Exactly, the last interval's length is `1`. Thanks!

Comment: @Ziezi You've already eliminated anything `>=5.0` in the previous `If`, so just `ElseIf input >= 4.5 Then` is fine

Comment: (Also - this gives *really* sharp grading changes at the boundaries - from 3.2 input to 3.3 input is an output change of 1.84, from 3.3 input to 3.4 input is an output change of 1.84, from 3.4 input to 3.5 input  is an output change of **2.65**, from 3.5 input to 3.6 input is an output change of 1.92, from 3.6 input to 3.7 input is an output change of 1.92...  You would get a smoother approximation from a cubic equation such as `y = 0.0015x^3 - 0.1115x^2 + 4.545x - 5.5277`)

Comment: @Chronocidal please, formulate it as an answer and the least that I will do is upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a Frame Challenge:

At the moment, this grading system gives a *really* sharp change in the grading structure at the boundaries.  For example, take a look at the following conversions:
[image: from 3.2 input to 3.3 input is an output change of 1.84, from 3.3 input to 3.4 input is an output change of 1.84, from 3.4 input to 3.5 input is an output change of 2.65, from 3.5 input to 3.6 input is an output change of 1.92, from 3.6 input to 3.7 input is an output change of 1.92]

A Grading **Curve** is generally called that for a reason - to give a smooth distribution and transition.  If you were to drop a cubic trendline on your graph, you can *almost* (but not quite) get there with `y = 0.0015x^3 - 0.1115x^2 + 4.545x - 5.5277`:
[image: Graph showing trendline and converted values]
(I have circled the sharp transitions, and the fact that the equation given currently goes negative at `x=2`)

Comment: That is an interesting observation - the largest bump is at the fail/pass point, 3.00, i.e. the pass threshold of the scale in the second column is 3.00. 
Having that in mind, should the scale Curve be smooth or should it reflect the characteristics of the grading system?